# Simple probability doubt regarding relation between two events.

Tags: probability

Say there is a competition with 3 participants A, B, and C. There are no ties.

We know that A does not come 3rd. So we can say that the probability of A coming 1st/2nd is 0.5

So will it be correct to say that the probability of the 1st/2nd position being occupied by A is also 0.5 with the probability of it being occupied by B or C being 0.25? Or will it still be 1/3?

Comment: If all we know is that $A$ did not place third, we have no way to assign probabilities to the other two positions.

Comment: Wait what, why is that, can't we say its 50/50 that A comes 1st?

Comment: assuming all possible arrival orders are equiprobable.  Your second option is plain wrong - the probabilities would not sum to 1 (1/2+1/3+1/3=7/6), which is bad for the environment :-)

Comment: If you have no information about an event, you can't simply make up probabilities.  It would be different if, say, we were told that, a priori, each of $A,B,C$ had equal chances of appearing in any position.  But we weren't told that.

Comment: @MBobrik Sorry for the vague statement, what was in my mind was (0.5 for A and 0.25 for B and C) OR (1/3 for each). I love the environment!

Comment: @lulu lets say we live in an ideal universe and everything is equiprobable

Comment: Well, that needs to be added to the problem description.  But, yes, if we knew that, a priori, each order was possible then excluding $A$ from position $3$ means that $A$ now has n equal chance of being in either of the other positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your possible outcomes given that A is not in 3rd place are (order 1st, 2nd, 3rd):

BA C 
AB C 
CA B 
AC B

The probability that A is in the 1st position is 1/2, B 1/4, C 1/4. Same for the second positions.

Comment: Reading this answer I realise how stupid my question actually was.
Thank you for your time good sir.

Comment: Hey - go easy on yourself! Probability can be very confusing, especially at first, and things are only clear in hindsight (and with practice).